# Combine multiple histograms ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several character variables with the same dimensions of outcome that I would like to compare. I am able to create a hsitogram for each of these variables:

`ggplot(MD, aes())+ geom_bar(aes(x = vielfalt_alter), stat = "count")`

[image]

and
`ggplot(MD, aes())+ geom_bar(aes(x = vielfalt_bildung), stat = "count")`
[image]

How can I combine the two histograms, in a way that the bars for each value stand beside each other and the variables are distinguishable via different colours?

```
dput(MD3)
structure(list(vielfalt_alter = c("Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, NA, "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "k. A.", NA, "Eher vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", NA, NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Nicht vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", NA, NA, "Eher vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", NA, 
NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig"), vielfalt_bildung = c("Eher vielfältig", 
"Nicht vielfältig", NA, NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", NA, NA, "Eher vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
NA, NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
NA, NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", NA, NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "k. A.", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "k. A.", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig"), vielfalt_geschlecht = c("Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", NA, NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", NA, NA, "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
NA, NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "k. A.", NA, "Nicht vielfältig", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "k. A.", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
NA, NA, "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Nicht vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", NA, NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"k. A.", "Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "k. A.", 
NA, "Nicht vielfältig", "k. A.", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig"), vielfalt_kultur = c("Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", NA, NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", NA, NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
NA, NA, "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
NA, NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", 
"Nicht vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", NA, NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig"), vielfalt_körper = c("Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", NA, NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"k. A.", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
NA, NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", NA, NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
NA, "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
NA, NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Nicht vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", NA, NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"k. A.", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "k. A.", NA, "Eher vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "k. A.", NA, "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "k. A.", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig"), vielfalt_sozial = c("Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", NA, NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", NA, NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", NA, 
NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Eher vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "k. A.", 
NA, NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", NA, NA, "Eher vielfältig", NA, "Teilweise vielfältig", 
NA, "Eher vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "k. A.", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "k. A.", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "k. A.", NA, "Eher nicht vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", NA, "Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Eher vielfältig", 
"Eher vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Teilweise vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", 
"Sehr vielfältig", "Sehr vielfältig", "Teilweise vielfältig", 
"Eher nicht vielfältig", "Eher nicht vielfältig")), row.names = c(NA, 
-114L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(MD)`?

Comment: These are not histograms, but bar plots. You need to get your data into long format to plot in the way you describe. This is straightforward, but you need to share your data for us to show you how to do it (as Quinten suggests).

Comment: @Quinten I did :)

Comment: Looks like you have your data in wide format, two variables in two columns (for which you have drawn the plots). Convert those two columns into tidy format (one new column) using gather function. Then you can call the new column to have the required plot with color differentiation. If you need the correct code and answer, please provide sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pivot your data into long format:

```r
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(MD3[1:2], 1:2),
       aes(x = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

You can even plot all your columns this way with no extra effort

```r
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(MD3, tidyr::everything()),
       aes(x = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

If you need to change the labels in the legend and x axis, use `labs`

```r
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(MD3[1:2], 1:2),
       aes(x = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_light() +
  labs(x = 'My x variables', fill = 'My categories')
```

[image]

To remove NA values, filter them out of your data frame to start with:

```r
ggplot(subset(tidyr::pivot_longer(MD3[1:2], 1:2), !is.na(value)),
       aes(x = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_light() +
  labs(x = 'My x variables', fill = 'My categories')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! Is there a way to drop the  NAs?

Comment: @LucasLeonhard sure -see my update

Comment: I got one last question: Is it possible to order the x-axis like this: c("Nicht vielfältig","Eher nicht vielfältig","Teilweise vielfältig","Eher vielfältig","Sehr vielfältig","k. A.") ? I tried to order the values in the data.frame but it did not change the plot

Comment: @LucasLeonhard You need to convert the column to a factor variable and then set the factor levels as you want them

Comment: @AllanCameron, your answer is far more sophisticated and comprehensive. Even I am surprised. As I see LucasLeonhard is new to the platform (I too am a novice). I saw he first accepted your answer. Then when I put my answer, he did select mine, probably without knowing that it will shift the selected answer from yours to mine. I think ideally he should have just upticked my answer and accepted your answer as the solution. I guess so..:)

Answer (score 2):

Given your data frame name is 'MD', you can try this.

```
tidy_data = gather(MD, new_col, value, factor_key=TRUE)

tidy_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, fill=new_col)) +
  geom_bar(stat='count', position = "dodge")+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]
If you want the plot only for two columns you can do this.

```
tidy_data %>% 
filter(new_col %in% c('vielfalt_alter', 'vielfalt_bildung'))%>%
ggplot(aes(value, fill=new_col)) +
  geom_bar(stat='count', position = "dodge")+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]